# Continuity of composition with polynomial implies continuity of both functions?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity

Let $P:[a,b]\rightarrow I$ be a polynomial with $I=P([a,b])$ (that is, $I$ is the image of $P$) and $f:I\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a function such that $f\circ P$ is continuous, prove that $f$ is continuous. Here $f\circ P$ denotes the composition of $f$ and $P$.

Is the hypothesis "polynomial" needed? (can't it be continuous instead of polynomial?)

Edit: Added the condition $I=P([a,b])$ otherwise as stated by Kelenner and José Carlos Santos there is a counterexample with $I=[-1,1]$, $P(x)=x^{2}$ and $f(x)=sign(x)$ if $x\neq 0$ and $f(0)=1$.

Comment: Your statement of what it means for $f$ to be discontinuous at $p$ is completely wrong. Do you know how to negate quantified statements and implications?

Comment: I've removed the sketch as it was wrong and I know how to negate the statements. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $P: [a,b] \to I = P[[a,b]]$ be a polynomial, and $f: I \to \mathbb{R}$ a function such that $f \circ P$ is continuous. 
Then $P$ is a quotient map (as it is closed, as a continuous map (the only thing I need to know about polynomials) from a compact space to a Hausdorff space) and so if $O \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is open, we know that $(f \circ P)^{-1}[O]$ is open in $[a,b]$ by continuity of $f \circ P$, and this set equals $P^{-1}[f^{-1}[O]]$ and as $P$ is quotient, $f^{-1}[O]$ is open in $I$. So $f$ is continuous.

The real line and intervals and polynomials are red herrings. It's a consequence of basic general topology which follows from continuity and compactness.